# Proportion of amino acids from a random polymer of U and C

Tags: molecular-biology, homework

> A protein synthesis assay was carried out in vitro. A
>   polyribonucleotide containing U and C in proportion 1:5 (positions of
>   U and C are random) was used as a template. Which amino acids and in
>   what proportions will be incorporated into the synthesized polypeptide
>   molecules?
>
> А. 1Phe : 5Pro : 3Leu.
>
> B. 1Leu : 1Pro : 1Ser : 1Phe.
>
> C. 1Phe : 5Ser : 5Pro : 5Leu.
>
> D. 1Phe : 25Pro : 5Ser : 5Leu.
>
> E. 5Leu : 5Pro.

First thing I am not sure is whether only U and C is there. I have tried solving this sum taking both the conditions into consideration . I also tried solving it from options but could not succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to mention is that this is the type of experiment that [Marshall Nirenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Warren_Nirenberg) performed in order to break the genetic code, and for which he got the Nobel prize in 1968. We stand on the shoulders of giants.

If the ratio is U:C, 1:5, then it is easy to calculate the probability of encountering each of the 8 possible codons composed by just U and C. So for example:

the probability of UUU is (1/6)<sup>3</sup>

the probability of UUC is (1/6)<sup>2</sup>*(5/6)

and so on.

Here's a Table that gives all of the values and demonstrates that the answer is (D).

[image]